# Export rgl object to Powerpoint as 3D Model

Tags: r, powerpoint, blender, rgl

TL DR: Posted the problem got some comments solved it and now leaving the question open for better suggestions. Thank you StackOverflow :)

Currently i was working on a molecular model in rgl which i would like to import as a 3D Model into Microsoft Powerpoint. This should be an easy task since rgl can export .ply objects which should be supported by powerpoint.

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
spheres3d(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, radius = .32, col = "#45caff")
writePLY("Nitrogen.ply",format="ascii",withColors = T) # WRONG CODE!
```

The code above should generate a sphere at the origin in a blue color. This is correctly shown in the rgl plot which opens after open3d() is executed.
[blueSphereImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJJA5.png)

After I import the model into Powerpoint the color is lost.[whiteSphereInPowerpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLlwe.png)
(on the screenshot the Shadow seems blueish i tried this with a red Sphere as well no difference and not what i expected)

How to export PLY from rgl to PowerPoint with Colors?

EDIT: I got the exported PLY working in Blender now the last step is PowerPoint but i am failing over again.
I found some reports of powerpoint not supporting vertex-color, can anyone confirm ?

Working export writePLY function:

```
writePLY("Nitrogen.ply",withColor=T)
```

Screenshot out of Blender: [BlenderScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KovU.png)

How to export from Blender with VERTEX to Powerpoint ?

EDIT: Solved it through import .ply in Blender export as .glb and then Import in Powerpoint. [paclubutrazol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQHDB.png)

I will leave this question open since i think there could be a better way of doing this. Thank you for your support. Yesterday I failed for 5 hours to decide to post this problem to solve it with your moral support in round about 2 hours. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you tried the OBJ and STL formats instead of PLY?

Comment: also, you can try the [vrmlgen](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/vrmlgen/index.html) package, which generates VRML files. These files are embeddable in PowerPoint with a plugin.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent STL and OBJ do not support color if exported from rgl sp these wont work. (I tried :)) I would prefer a solution without a plugin but i will check it out.

Comment: HTML-based formats like `ioslides_presentation` in RMarkdown support `rgl` output without any hassle.  Maybe switch to one of those instead of Powerpoint?

Comment: @user2554330 I will check them out. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Another possibility is the in-development export of rgl scenes to glTF files using the rgl2gltf package.  This is still incomplete, but should eventually be able to export most aspects of rgl scenes.